# Eclipse does not run Xdebug or Zend debugger on Mac OSX 10.8.2?

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug, zend-debugger

I was able to successfully install both Zend as well as Xdebugger. Verified by Phpinfo as well as Eclipse verifies the Zend debug successfully installed. Although whenever I run debug from eclipse for

```
Xdebug it hangs at 57%`
```

and for Zend debugger

```
the browser keeps processing/busy but nothing happens
```

Unsure what is causing this
-> Firewall issues?
-> No Selinux in Mac so not sure if it is a permissions issue

Any clues would be helpful. 
Thank you.

Comment: FYI, i stalled @ 57% too :-(

Comment: Thanks @Chris Why a -1? If downvote then please have the decency to atleast provide feedback whoever downvoted. I want to downvote the downvote.

Comment: it wasn't me (o.o)  People on here can be quite ruthless ...BTW did you ever get your PHP debugging environment setup?

Comment: i think i got this working, let me know if you need some help.

Comment: @Chris Do you know what solved that for you? Please do share what worked for you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

it seems like a miss configuration of debug. I will try to help you showing my working configurations.

This is my php.ini piece for xdebug.

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9060
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_autostart=On
```

It is important to note about the parameter debug.remote_host. If your client side is not allowed here, you will stuck on 57%. The value here is the IP of the machine where you are running eclipse. If you are running apache/php and eclipse in the same machine the localhost IP should work.

Adapt zend_extension parameter to your world.

Other reason you can stop in 57% is the web site is not running. Apache/PHP only will send xdebug metadata if the site is running. If you got an internal error, for example, you will be stuck on 57% also. Eclipse stops on 57% waiting for a xdebug session. You must be sure apache/php started a debug session.

Make sure the Debug configuration on eclipse is using the correct PHP server. If you are trying to run eclipse in an invalid PHP server or a PHP server which is not well configured you will stop on 57% also. So review the PHP server parameters on Debug Configurations.

Other important review you have to made is about the Xdebug configuration for eclipse. The port Debug port field must be filled with the same value of parameter xdebug.remote_port. If they are different you will be stuck in 57% also.

Please, let me know if it was helpful.

Comment: Will try the solutions you mentioned. Thanks for the elaborate response, so much better than saying go look at other answers.

Comment: I know what are you talking about. In the beginning with eclipse php and xdebug I had the same issue several times. Now I believe has some answers to help about this issue. thanks for the reviews.

Answer (score -1):

For Xdebug, this is likely a misconfigured path mapping in Eclipse. There are 10s of questions related to that here on stackoverflow and 100s of hits on google. Please check there first.